# accesing html form array inside javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

how can i access an array, defined in the form, inside javascript.
e.g 
i have defined an integer array inside the web form like

```
<%  using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       int[] ctid = ViewData["ct"] as int[];
       var x = 0;    
       %>
```

now i want to access this array(ctid) inside javascript, how can i do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the array and write it out to a Javascript array.

```
%>
//page JavaScript
var js_ctid = new Array(<% =ctid.length %>);

<%

//C# code
for (int=0; i<ctid.length; i++)
{
    Response.Write("js_ctid[" + i + "] = " + js_ctid[i]);
}
```

You could also try the JavaScriptSerializer Class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to turn it into a JSON object